# Prevent css from loading on contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Is there any way in which you can prevent the preloading style which contact form 7 brings into your page when the short code is loaded. I basically want the bare basics of contact form 7 as I have my own style for the form, however contact form 7 conflicts with this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you out : http://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/